# Html5 form pattern latin characters vocals áéíóú Çç ü

Tags: html, character-encoding, forms, iso-8859-1

i'm trying to validate input form html5, it works in my local web server, but when upload to hosting doesnt work in this characters: accented characters (vocals) like áéíóú.

so i have tried changing the encoding, is this the best practice?

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;" charset="ISO-8859-1">
<html>
<head></head>
    <body>
        <form>
        Input:<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúü\-_çÇ& ]+"  required />
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What does the server-side code try to do with the values it gets? (The "best practice" is almost certainly to use UTF-8 instead of an ISO-8859 encoding, not restrict the characters, and deal with any input correctly on the server side, but it depends on your desired outcome.)

Comment: my mistake, if I use: 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 doesn't work, with <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;" charset="ISO-8859-1">  it works

Comment: thanks very much, i have saved the file in the encoding UTF-8 and worked well.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The charset described by the meta tag is not the page's encoding, it's just *your* claim of what the encoding is.

The actual encoding of the page is whatever encoding you used in your text editor to save the file. It is also possible that the hosting changes the encoding of the file but probably unlikely.

You probably want your tag just to be:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Remember to ensure that you save the file in UTF-8 encoding. (Usually "Encoding" in Save As-dialog)

---

It is also possible that the hosting is sending an actual HTTP header with charset - this will override any meta tag you have. You can see if this is the case by using Google Chrome Developer Tools Network tab for example.

Comment: thanks, worked with save with UTF8 file, and <meta charset="UTF-8"> on the firsts lines, and works !  :)

Comment: @FedericoPereyra consider accepting the answer, see the checkmark on the left of the answer :)

Comment: Why `<meta charset="UTF-8">`, not `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`??

Comment: it's shorter to write and looks cleaner to me :P